# Problema de las 8 reinas en Java

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un código para colocar 8 reinas en un tablero de ajedrez sin que se amenacen unas a otras, pero solo alcanzo a colocar 7 reinas bien y la 8 se coloca erróneamente. La verdad no sé dónde esta el problema.
Tengo dos métodos que son la lógica del programa: el primero posicion verdadera analiza si existe una amenaza donde se quiere colocar la reina, el otro método `posicionVerdadera` (recursivo) hace todo el llamado al primer método.

```
public class Operacion {
       //Numero reinas
    private final int NR=8;
    private int[][] tablero= new int[NR][NR];;
    
    String letras[]= {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};
    public void imprimir() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++) {
            System.out.print("    "+letras[i]+"  ");
        }System.out.print("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NR; j++) {
            
                if (i==0 && j==0) {
                    System.out.print(i+1);
                }
                else if (j>=0) {
                    if (j==0) {
                        System.out.print(i+1);
                        
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("   "+tablero[i][j]+"   ");
                        
                        if (j==7) {
                            System.out.print("   "+tablero[i][j]+"   ");
                            System.out.println("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public boolean posicionVerdadera(int fila, int columna) {
        
        //verificar que fila actual sea segura, verificando cada columna de esta
        for (int j = 0; j < columna; j++) 
            if (tablero[fila][j]==1) 
                return false; 
      
        //verifica diagonal superior del lado izquierdo sea segura
        for (int i=fila, j=columna; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--) 
            if (tablero[i][j]==1) 
                return false; 
      
        //verifica diagonal inferior del lado izquierdo sea segura
        for (int i=fila, j=columna; j>=0 && i<NR; i++, j--) 
            if (tablero[i][j]==1) 
                return false; 
      
        //verifica que no hayan atacantes ni en sus lados, ni en sus diagonales
        return true; 
        
        
    }
    
    public boolean solucion(int columna) {
        //Caso base: si la solucion es la correcta
        if (columna >=NR) {
            return true;
        }
        //Se considera la columna actual como una posible solución y se verifica
        for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++) {
            //verifica si se puede colocar  en el tablero[i][columna]
            if (posicionVerdadera(i, columna)) {
                
                tablero[i][columna]=1;
                //se invoca la funcion recursiva para dar solucion  a ls demad reinas del tablero
                if (solucion(columna+1)) {
                    
                    return true;
                }
                
                tablero[i][columna]=0;
                
            }   
        }
        //si no hay solucion la renia puede se colocada en ninguna fila de esta columna
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean inicializar() {
        
        if (solucion(0)==false) {
            System.out.println("No Hay solucion");
            return false;
        }
        imprimir();
        
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

Cuando ya voy a correr el programa se colocan en total las 8 reinas, pero hay 2 que generan conflicto entre ellas y se amenazan.
[image: Impresión del resultado final]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estoy de acuerdo con la otra solución aportada. Tu código es algo confuso y no puedo asegurarte que todos los chequeos se estén haciendo bien, pero uno de tus principales problemas es el método de impresión. Lo que estás imprimiendo NO es lo que hay almacenado en el array tablero.

Podemos simplificar y clarificar tu método imprimir de la siguiente forma

```
public void imprimirBis() {
        
    // Imprime cabecera
    System.out.print("   ");
        
    for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + letras[i] + "     ");
    }
        
    System.out.print("\n");
        
    // Imprime tablero - filas 0 a (NR - 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++) {
            
        // Imprime índice de fila
        System.out.print((i + 1));
            
        // Imprime fila i - Columnas 0 a (NR - 1)
        for (int j = 0; j < NR; j++) {
            System.out.print("   " + tablero[i][j] + "   ");
        }
            
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }       
}
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo sin cambiar nada más de tu código

```
    A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H     
1   1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   

2   0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0   

3   0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0   

4   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1   

5   0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   

6   0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0   

7   0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0   

8   0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
```

Lo primero que me ha extrañado es que con tu versión de imprimir, la posición (0,0) o 1A debería ser igual a 1 ya que es la primera reina y no hay ninguna otra en el tablero. Y efectivamente, con un imprimir más legible, sin if anidados en su bucle interior ahí aparece un 1.

La situación que se te muestra a ti, no está realmente en el tablero.

Por lo que veo, la solución mostrada es correcta.

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes en la función posicionVerdadera. Te dejas por repasar la columna y parte de la fila y lo mismo te ocurre con las diagonales, no las recorres por completo.

Echa un ojo a la función reconstruida tal y como yo la abordaría (atiende a los comentarios):

```
 public boolean posicionVerdadera(int fila, int columna, int[][] tablero) {
    
    //1. verificar que la fila actual sea segura, verificando cada columna de esta (se incluye VERIFICAR TODA LA FILA)
    
    
    for (int iterColumna = 0; iterColumna < tablero.length; iterColumna++) 
        if (iterColumna == columna) continue;
        else if (tablero[fila][iterColumna]==1) return false; 
  
    
    
    //2. verificar que la columna actual sea segura, verificando cada fila de esta. (este código no lo tenías) 
    
    //aqui no deberias verificar todas las columnas de la fila??
    for (int iterFila = 0; iterFila < tablero.length; iterFila++) 
        if (iterFila == fila) continue;
        else if (tablero[iterFila][columna]==1) return false;
    
    
    
    //LO MISMO TE OCURRE CON LA VERIFICACION DE LAS DIAGONALES, NO LAS VERIFICAS POR COMPLETO
    //LOS PASOS 3 Y 4 SI LO HACEN.
    
    //3. verificar que la diagonal superior (pendiente positiva) sea segura
    
    //buscamos el extremo izquierdo de la diagonal superior
    int iterColumna = columna;
    int iterFila = fila;
    for (;iterColumna>0;iterColumna--) iterFila++;
    //luego recorremos toda la diagonal excepto la posicion marcada por los parametros fila,columna
    for (; iterFila>=0; iterFila--, iterColumna++) { 
        
        //System.out.println("iterFila = " + iterFila + ", iterColumna = " + iterColumna + "\n");
    
        if ((iterFila == fila) && (iterColumna == columna)) continue;
        if (tablero[iterFila][iterColumna]==1) return false; 
    }
  
    //4. verificar que la diagonal inferior (pendiente negativa) sea segura
    
    //buscamos el extremo izquierdo de la diagonal infgerior
    iterColumna = columna;
    iterFila = fila;
    for (;iterColumna>0;iterColumna--) iterFila--;
    //luego recorremos toda la diagonal excepto la posicion marcada por los parametros fila,columna
    for (; iterFila<tablero.length; iterFila++, iterColumna++) { 
        
        System.out.println("iterFila = " + iterFila + ", iterColumna = " + iterColumna + "\n");
    
        if ((iterFila == fila) && (iterColumna == columna)) continue;
        if (tablero[iterFila][iterColumna]==1) return false; 
    }
  
    //verifica que no hayan atacantes ni en sus lados, ni en sus diagonales (y en la columna??? es decir, arriba y abajo???)
    return true;    
    
}
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo una seria reorganización del código que te ayudaría a un mejor testeo y mucho mejor mantenimiento y reutilización.

Un saludo.